# Component bindings acting strange

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn how to use the component binding feature.
So I wrote a component:

```
'use strict';
var module = angular.module("Test", []);

module.controller("Controller2", Controller2);
module.component("compo2", {
    controller: "Controller2",
    bindings: {
        url: "@",
        thing: "<"
    }
});


Controller2.$inject = ["$scope"];
function Controller2($scope) {
    var self = this;
    this.$onInit = function () {
    }  
}
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="./Test/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="./compoTest.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="Test">
        <compo2 url="www.test.com" thing="a911"> T.E.S.T </compo2>
</body>
</html>
```

I read that both "@" and "<" are used for one-directional binding.
The "@" binding works fine, but the "<" binding won't bind strings (like "a911")
and it will actually throw an error if I try to set the 'thing' attribute to "911a" because it's not a number.

Am I doing something wrong or is it the expected behaviour?

Comment: try `thing="'a911'"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `<` one way binding you can

In controller where your compo2 component stays, assign a string to a variable like `this.myString = "a911"` and

with `controllerAs = "vm"` syntax :

```
<compo2 url="www.test.com" thing="vm.myString"> T.E.S.T </compo2>
```